# Code that once returned Git Installation Access Token no longer does so

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, github, github-api

Some time ago I provided [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48679620/7836976) answer to a question. the code sample is one which I've used in several applications without any issue.

Now, I'm trying to use it again but when I run it I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'access_tokens_url' of undefined

The `access_tokens_url` isn't in the response as you can see:

```
{ status: 200,
  statusText: 'OK',
  headers: 
   { server: 'GitHub.com',
     date: 'Tue, 13 Nov 2018 19:48:12 GMT',
     'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
     'content-length': '2',
     connection: 'close',
     status: '200 OK',
     'cache-control': 'public, max-age=60, s-maxage=60',
     vary: 'Accept',
     etag: '"5b49dc572fac1de90f6dcbe96af712d9"',
     'x-github-media-type': 'github.machine-man-preview; format=json',
     'access-control-expose-headers': 'ETag, Link, Location, Retry-After, X-GitHub-OTP, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-OAuth-Scopes, X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes, X-Poll-Interval, X-GitHub-Media-Type',
     'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
     'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload',
     'x-frame-options': 'deny',
     'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
     'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block',
     'referrer-policy': 'origin-when-cross-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin',
     'content-security-policy': 'default-src \'none\'',
     'x-github-request-id': 'F6A0:223A:3E7AF15:7F929C0:5BEB2A7B' },
  config: 
   { adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
     transformRequest: { '0': [Function: transformRequest] },
     transformResponse: { '0': [Function: transformResponse] },
     timeout: 0,
     xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
     xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
     maxContentLength: -1,
     validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
     headers: 
      { Accept: 'application/vnd.github.machine-man-preview+json',
        Authorization: 'Bearer blablabla',
        'User-Agent': 'axios/0.18.0' },
     method: 'get',
     url: 'https://api.github.com/app/installations',
     data: undefined },
  request: 
   ClientRequest {
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { socket: [Function],
        abort: [Function],
        aborted: [Function],
        error: [Function],
        timeout: [Function],
        prefinish: [Function: requestOnPrefinish] },
     _eventsCount: 6,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     output: [],
     outputEncodings: [],
     outputCallbacks: [],
     outputSize: 0,
     writable: true,
     _last: true,
     upgrading: false,
     chunkedEncoding: false,
     shouldKeepAlive: false,
     useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
     sendDate: false,
     _removedConnection: false,
     _removedContLen: false,
     _removedTE: false,
     _contentLength: 0,
     _hasBody: true,
     _trailer: '',
     finished: true,
     _headerSent: true,
     socket: 
      TLSSocket {
        _tlsOptions: [Object],
        _secureEstablished: true,
        _securePending: false,
        _newSessionPending: false,
        _controlReleased: true,
        _SNICallback: null,
        servername: null,
        npnProtocol: undefined,
        alpnProtocol: false,
        authorized: true,
        authorizationError: null,
        encrypted: true,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 9,
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: null,
        _parent: null,
        _host: 'api.github.com',
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: false,
        domain: null,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: false,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        _bytesDispatched: 626,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: undefined,
        _server: null,
        ssl: null,
        _requestCert: true,
        _rejectUnauthorized: true,
        parser: null,
        _httpMessage: [Circular],
        read: [Function],
        _consuming: true,
        _idleNext: null,
        _idlePrev: null,
        _idleTimeout: -1,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 24,
        [Symbol(bytesRead)]: 937 },
     connection: 
      TLSSocket {
        _tlsOptions: [Object],
        _secureEstablished: true,
        _securePending: false,
        _newSessionPending: false,
        _controlReleased: true,
        _SNICallback: null,
        servername: null,
        npnProtocol: undefined,
        alpnProtocol: false,
        authorized: true,
        authorizationError: null,
        encrypted: true,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 9,
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: null,
        _parent: null,
        _host: 'api.github.com',
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: false,
        domain: null,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: false,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        _bytesDispatched: 626,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: undefined,
        _server: null,
        ssl: null,
        _requestCert: true,
        _rejectUnauthorized: true,
        parser: null,
        _httpMessage: [Circular],
        read: [Function],
        _consuming: true,
        _idleNext: null,
        _idlePrev: null,
        _idleTimeout: -1,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 24,
        [Symbol(bytesRead)]: 937 },
        _header: 'GET /app/installations HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept: application/vnd.github.machine-man-preview+json\r\nAuthorization: Bearer blablabla\r\nUser-Agent: axios/0.18.0\r\nHost: api.github.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
     _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
     agent: 
      Agent {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        defaultPort: 443,
        protocol: 'https:',
        options: [Object],
        requests: {},
        sockets: [Object],
        freeSockets: {},
        keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
        keepAlive: false,
        maxSockets: Infinity,
        maxFreeSockets: 256,
        maxCachedSessions: 100,
        _sessionCache: [Object] },
     socketPath: undefined,
     timeout: undefined,
     method: 'GET',
     path: '/app/installations',
     _ended: true,
     res: 
      IncomingMessage {
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: false,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 3,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        socket: [Object],
        connection: [Object],
        httpVersionMajor: 1,
        httpVersionMinor: 1,
        httpVersion: '1.1',
        complete: true,
        headers: [Object],
        rawHeaders: [Array],
        trailers: {},
        rawTrailers: [],
        upgrade: false,
        url: '',
        method: null,
        statusCode: 200,
        statusMessage: 'OK',
        client: [Object],
        _consuming: true,
        _dumped: false,
        req: [Circular],
        responseUrl: 'https://api.github.com/app/installations',
        redirects: [],
        read: [Function] },
     aborted: undefined,
     timeoutCb: null,
     upgradeOrConnect: false,
     parser: null,
     maxHeadersCount: null,
     _redirectable: 
      Writable {
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _options: [Object],
        _redirectCount: 0,
        _redirects: [],
        _requestBodyLength: 0,
        _requestBodyBuffers: [],
        _onNativeResponse: [Function],
        _currentRequest: [Circular],
        _currentUrl: 'https://api.github.com/app/installations' },
     [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: 
      { accept: [Array],
        authorization: [Array],
        'user-agent': [Array],
        host: [Array] } },
  data: [] }
```

I'm trying to spot if anything is different in my code but I can't see anything. Is it possible something has changed with the APII and if so, how can I resolve this issue?

**Additional Info.**
This curl command:

```
curl -i -H "Authorization: Bearer blablabla" -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.machine-man-preview+json" https://api.github.com/app/installations
```

should also return the data response but with it I get:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: GitHub.com
Date: Wed, 14 Nov 2018 20:43:04 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 5
Status: 200 OK
Cache-Control: public, max-age=60, s-maxage=60
Vary: Accept
ETag: "5b49dc572fac1de90f6dcbe96af712d9"
X-GitHub-Media-Type: github.machine-man-preview; format=json
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: ETag, Link, Location, Retry-After, X-GitHub-OTP, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-OAuth-Scopes, X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes, X-Poll-Interval, X-GitHub-Media-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;  preload
X-Frame-Options: deny
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Referrer-Policy: origin-when-cross-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'
X-GitHub-Request-Id: E867:223A:47CF7F2:924E87D:5BEC88D8

[

]
```

so I don't think it's my code.

As I see it there is either an option with GitHub or with the way I've configured the GitHub app. An ideas?

**Additional Info 2**

A possible step further! I noticed the GitHub ap wasn't installed so I've that done now. The issue I'm having now is that when I execut my program I get this:

```
Unable to authenticate
```

**Additional Info 3**

I regenerated my PEM key. Now I'm getting this:

```
{ HttpError: {"message":"Validation Failed","errors":[{"message":"The listed users and repositories cannot be searched either because the resources do not exist or you do not have permission to view them.","resource":"Search","field":"q","code":"invalid"}],"documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3/search/"}
    at response.text.then.message (/Users/me/git/issue-tracker/node_modules/@octokit/rest/lib/request/request.js:72:19)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
  name: 'HttpError',
  code: 422,
  status: undefined,
  headers: 
   { 'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
 'access-control-expose-headers': 'ETag, Link, Location, Retry-After, X-GitHub-OTP, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-OAuth-Scopes, X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes, X-Poll-Interval, X-GitHub-Media-Type',
     'cache-control': 'no-cache',
     connection: 'close',
     'content-length': '306',
     'content-security-policy': 'default-src \'none\'',
     'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
     date: 'Thu, 15 Nov 2018 21:14:49 GMT',
     'referrer-policy': 'origin-when-cross-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin',
     server: 'GitHub.com',
     status: '422 Unprocessable Entity',
     'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload',
     'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
     'x-frame-options': 'deny',
     'x-github-media-type': 'github.v3; format=json, github.machine-man-preview; format=json',
     'x-github-request-id': 'DA17:447A:93639E1:1128EFAD:5BEDE1C8',
     'x-ratelimit-limit': '30',
     'x-ratelimit-remaining': '25',
     'x-ratelimit-reset': '1542316508',
     'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block' } }
{ HttpError: {"message":"Validation Failed","errors":[{"message":"The listed users and repositories cannot be searched either because the resources do not exist or you do not have permission to view them.","resource":"Search","field":"q","code":"invalid"}],"documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3/search/"}
    at response.text.then.message (/Users/me/git/issue-tracker/node_modules/@octokit/rest/lib/request/request.js:72:19)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
  name: 'HttpError',
  code: 422,
  status: undefined,
  headers: 
   { 'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
     'access-control-expose-headers': 'ETag, Link, Location, Retry-After, X-GitHub-OTP, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-OAuth-Scopes, X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes, X-Poll-Interval, X-GitHub-Media-Type',
     'cache-control': 'no-cache',
     connection: 'close',
     'content-length': '306',
     'content-security-policy': 'default-src \'none\'',
     'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
     date: 'Thu, 15 Nov 2018 21:14:49 GMT',
     'referrer-policy': 'origin-when-cross-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin',
     server: 'GitHub.com',
     status: '422 Unprocessable Entity',
     'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload',
     'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
     'x-frame-options': 'deny',
     'x-github-media-type': 'github.v3; format=json, github.machine-man-preview; format=json',
     'x-github-request-id': 'DA18:447A:93639E4:1128EFB5:5BEDE1C8',
     'x-ratelimit-limit': '30',
     'x-ratelimit-remaining': '24',
     'x-ratelimit-reset': '1542316508',
     'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block' } }
```

I'm a bit stumped with this one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue here was that a key in one of the parameters I was passing had a typo.